# Escape apostrophe as \' with c:out JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have an object field with person's last name.

If I use *${person.lastName}*, I get *O'Brian*

If I use

```
 <c:out value="${person.lastName}"/>
```

I get O'Brian

Both outputs breaks the next jsp code in IE

```
 <a href="#" 
    class="delete" 
    onclick="if(confirm('<c:out value="${application.lastName}"/> ' + _('Are you sure you want to delete this application?'))) {deleteApplication('${application.identifier}')};return false;"><bean:message key="application.delete"/></a>
```

because it gets transformed to

```
    onclick="if(confirm('O&#039;Brian '
```

or

```
    onclick="if(confirm('O'Brian '
```

I would need *O'Brian* to be escaped as *O\'Brian*

Any idea how to solve this issue?

## SOLUTION

The most elegant solutions seems to use a simple Tag.

```
package view;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport;

public class EscapeJS extends SimpleTagSupport {
    public String str;

    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
        getJspContext().getOut().print(str.replaceAll("\'", "\\\\'"));
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

}
```

Then place in WEB-INF a utils.tld file:

```
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.1//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd">
<taglib>
    <tlibversion>1.2</tlibversion>
    <jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
    <shortname>bean</shortname><uri>utilsTags</uri>
    <uri>utilsTags</uri>
    <tag>
        <name>escapeJS</name>
        <tagclass>view.EscapeJS</tagclass>
        <bodycontent>scriptless</bodycontent>
        <attribute>
            <name>str</name>
            <required>true</required>       
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue> 
        </attribute>                
    </tag>      
</taglib>
```

Then inside your jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="utils" uri="utilsTags" %>

<utils:escapeJS str="${application.firstName}"/>
```

Comment: It's insufficient to just escape the apostrophe. You should also escape the backslash, `\n`, `\r` and `\"`. If the string being escaped is user-controllable, then it also opens a security hole as it is possible to escape your escaping with something like `\';my_script();`

Answer (score 3):

You could define a new EL function that escapes strings for you.

E.g.

In Java

```
public class MyStringUtil {
  public static String escapeJs( String str )
  {
    // escape the string (e.g. replace ' with \')
  }
}
```

In a tag library descriptor file:

```
<function>
 <name>escapeJs</name>
 <function-class>package.to.MyStringUtil</function-class>
 <function-signature>
   java.lang.String escapeJs( java.lang.String )
 </function-signature>
</function>
```

Then in your JSP (assuming you've included your `.tld` with a prefix of `foo`:

```
<a href="#" 
  class="delete" 
  onclick="if(confirm('${foo:escapeJs(person.lastName)}' + _('Are you sure you want to delete this application?'))) {deleteApplication('${application.identifier}')};return false;"><bean:message key="application.delete"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store it as O'brian in the database, but before displaying it do a find replace to convert any ' to \'

Comment: I want to store the value as O'Brian, because most of the time I want to display it as O'Brian not as O'Brian

Comment: updated answer, looks like you need to find replace on ' to \' before displaying values.